# Max Points in Castle of Dr. Brain

Tags: castle-of-dr-brain

What is the maximum amount of points one can get in Castle of Dr. Brain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200 points is the max amount for Castle of Dr. Brain.  To get it, follow [this playlist](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=39E5AD3FF22DB3C6) I made from another user's videos(he only gets 199) and keep in mind this tip from this comment on the last vid:

> I got this on abandonware yesterday, and I found out where you missed the point.
>
> When I solved the Clock/Radio/Alarm/Bird puzzle in 80 seconds, I only got 6 points for it, bringing me a total of 34. When I tried it again, I restored from an earlier point, and won in 30 seconds, and received 7 new points, for a total of 35. However, this only gives you bragging rights, as the ending looks no different to me.
>
> I really can't find any other way to lose points.